# How to set required field ''State/Province' of add new address in My Address Book, magento 2?

Tags: magento2.2, address, addfield, required

Using magento 2.2, I want to set required on field **State/Province** in **Add New Address** in 'my address book'.

[image]

Comment: You need to add States?provinces in the Database, the required option works for States/Provinces available in Backend as Dropdown. Open Text field doesn't appear as required

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/146452)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can select `State` Required for particular Country from backend using the below path:

> Stores-> Configuration -> General -> State Options

here select country in `State is Required for` dropdown.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Go to `Admin > Stores > Settings > Configuration > General > General > State Options > State is Required for`, here select the countries for those state needs to be required.